# How do dune wrapped libraries with explicit module interfaces affect build speed?

Tags: ocaml, ocaml-dune

I'm working in a monorepo with a lot of OCaml libraries that are `(wrapped false)` (see [dune stanza reference](https://dune.readthedocs.io/en/stable/dune-files.html#library))

**Is using dune wrapped libraries with explicit module interfaces likely to reduce link times?**

For example, assume `binary` depends on `lib_a`:

```
- dune (declares `binary` library, which depends on `lib_a`)
- binary.ml
   / lib_a
       - dune (declares `lib_a` library)
       - lib_a_helpers.ml
       - lib_a_helpers.mli
       - lib_a.ml
       - lib_a.mli (does not expose any symbols from lib_a_helpers)
```

My mental model is:

- If `lib_a` uses `(wrapped true)` then the symbols from `lib_a_helpers.ml` will not be in the `lib_a.a`.
- Then the linker has fewer symbols to search through when creating
  `binary.opt`
- So I expect linking will be faster, but am not sure

Answer (score 0):

Using wrapped libraries can only slightly slow down the build time: the wrapped library adds another module (the library entry point) which re-exports aliases to some of the internal modules. In particular, it does not remove any modules from the library.